# Convert a Time to a formatted string in C#

Tags: c#, time, string-formatting

`Time.ToString("0.0")` shows up as a decimal "1.5" for instead of 1:30. How can I get it to display in a time format?

```
private void xTripSeventyMilesRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //calculation for the estimated time label
    Time = Miles / SeventyMph; 
    this.xTripEstimateLabel.Visible = true;
    this.xTripEstimateLabel.Text = "Driving at this speed the estimated travel time in hours is: " + Time.ToString("0.0") + " hrs";
}
```

Comment: What Type is Time?
is it float?

Answer (score 27):

```
Time.ToString("hh:mm")
```

Formats:

```
HH:mm  =  01:22  
hh:mm tt  =  01:22 AM  
H:mm  =  1:22  
h:mm tt  =  1:22 AM  
HH:mm:ss  =  01:22:45
```

**EDIT:** Since now we know the time is a `double` change the code to (assuming you want hours and minutes):

```
// This will handle over 24 hours
TimeSpan ts= System.TimeSpan.FromHours(Time);
string.Format("{0}:{1}", System.Math.Truncate(ts.TotalHours).ToString(), ts.Minutes.ToString());
```

or

```
// Keep in mind this could be bad if you go over 24 hours
DateTime.MinValue.AddHours(Time).ToString("H:mm");
```

Comment: this worked for me too, although I'd add that it's good practice to pass in a culture when doing .ToString(), either CultureInfo.InvariantCulture or CultureInfo.CurrentCulture (Microsoft FxCop recommends this too)

Comment: `Time.ToString("hh:mm")` gives me a format exception. (Seems like the colon must be escaped, except that the escape \ also needs to be escaped, so you end up with: `Time.ToString("hh\\:mm")`)

Answer (score 2):

I guess that `Time` is of type `TimeSpan`? In that case, [the documentation of TimeSpan.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632.aspx) can help you, in particular the pages

- [Standard TimeSpan Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286.aspx) and
- [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx).

If Time is a numeric data type, you can use [TimeSpan.FromHours](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromhours.aspx) to convert it to a TimeSpan first.

(EDIT: TimeSpan format strings were introduced in .NET 4.)

Answer (score 2):

If `Time` is a `System.Double`, then `System.TimeSpan.FromHours(Time).ToString();`

Comment: (System.TimeSpan.FromHours(Time).ToString()) works great thanks but how can i concatenate the string to out put only 8:30 instead of 00:00:00.00000

Comment: string.Format("{0:HH:mm}", DateTime.MinValue + TimeSpan.FromHours(Time))

Comment: In case you're wondering, the more elegant methods proposed by other users are new additions to .NET 4.0

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you work in a 24-hour base, it's very important to use `HH:mm` and NOT `hh:mm`.

Sometimes I mistakenly write `hh:mm`, and then instead of "13:45" I get "01:45", and there's no way to know whether it's AM or PM (unless you use `tt`).

Answer (score 0):

If time is float or double you'll have to.
System.Math.Truncate(Time) to get the hours

and then (Time - System.Math.Truncate(Time))* 60 
to get the minutes.

Comment: Yes it is a double, but I'm new to C# and programming in general this is my second assignment in class so could you please elaborate more on how to use this. I'll do the legwork just need direction.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of the responses guys and gals i used this `DateTime.MinValue.AddHours(Time).ToString("H:mm");`for my program since it was the easiest one to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Create a timespan from you numeric variable:

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(Math.Floor(Time), (Time - Math.Floor(Time))*60);
```

Then, use the ToString method.