# C# parse DateTime String to time only

Tags: c#, string, datetime, parsing

I am new to C# and I have a string like "2021-06-14 19:27:14:979". Now I want to have only the time "19:27:14:979". So do I parse the string to a specific DateTime format and then convert it back to a string or would you parse or cut the string itself?

It is important that I keep the 24h format. I don't want AM or PM.

I haven't found any solution yet. I tried to convert it to DateTime like:

```
var Time1 = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff"); 
var Time2 = Time1.ToString("hh:mm:ss:fff");
```

But then I lost the 24h format.

Comment: Use the `TimeOfDay` property of your parsed DateTime.

Comment: Your code is almost working, but `ParseExact` needs two additional arguments: `var Time1 = DateTime.ParseExact("2021-06-14 19:27:14:979", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff", null, DateTimeStyles.None);`

Comment: if it is always this format, you can do this `string dateTime = "2021-06-14 19:27:14:979";
  string time = dateTime.Split(' ')[1];`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a Time to a formatted string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716920/convert-a-time-to-a-formatted-string-in-c-sharp)

Comment: If you want to be hip and cool use TimeOnly - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/date-time-and-time-zone-enhancements-in-net-6/#introducing-the-dateonly-and-timeonly-types

Comment: since .NET 6 you can use TimeOnly.Parse() to achieve this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/how-to-use-dateonly-timeonly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is almost working, but `ParseExact` needs two additional arguments and `ToString` needs upper-case `HH` for 24h format:

```
var Time1 = DateTime.ParseExact("2021-06-14 19:27:14:979", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff", null, DateTimeStyles.None);
var Time2 = Time1.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff");
```

Read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#uppercase-hour-h-format-specifier

Instead of passing `null` as format provider(means current culture) you might want to pass a specifc `CultureInfo`, for example `CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")`.

Answer (score 2):

You can just split it at the blank and take the last part like this

```
var timestamp = "2021-06-14 19:27:14:979";
var timePart = timestamp.Split(' ')[1];
```

in your case that seems easier than parsing into a DateTime and back into a string.